# making div height same as its contents

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a navigation bar with the following code , but i can't seem to get the outer div to be of the same height as that of the unordered list inside.

I tried display:inline-block too but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the html,

http://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/7Lyss/

HTML :

```
<div id="top_navigation_menu">
    <ul id="top_navigation_list">
        <li class="top_navigation_options">Home</li>
        <li class="top_navigation_options">Places</li>
        <li class="top_navigation_options">Travel</li>
        <li class="top_navigation_options">Stay</li>
        <li class="top_navigation_options">FAQs</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#top_navigation_menu{
position:absolute;
top:14%;
min-width: 50%;
background-color:#eee;
color:white;
}
#top_navigation_list{
list-style-type: none;
}
.top_navigation_options{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline` with `Ul` and display:inline-block with `li` css class. Something like this

```
#top_navigation_list{
list-style-type: none;
background-color:#000;
display:inline;
}
.top_navigation_options{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lyss/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin: 0` in `#top_navigation_list` to remove the default margin of an unordered list.

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lyss/2/)